# add component in bottom of android screen

Tags: android, layout

i m new in android developing.

i want to create custom tab bar in android like Iphone tab bar. i have found so much example to done this. but i would like to use only one XML file for tab bar and after include these to screens. i think it is possible with the help of layout but i don't have much idea.

if there are only one property of layout there implement component  at the bottom.

if anybody done this please provide some idea.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there is no need to take a frame.
just add your imagebutton in linearlayout with horizontal orientation and set gravity to bottom.
thats it!

thankx.

Answer (score 1):

You can take frame which is set to bottom with width="fill_parent" and take linear layout in that and set Button or Image button into that